# Session lost after a page redirect in PHP

Tags: php, session

When I use PHP header redirection, all session variables are lost... Some people say that adding exit(); just after the header(""); will solve the problem, but it doesn't seem to be the solution...

Is there a solution?

Here is how I store variable into the session:

```
include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $get[$key] = filter($value); // GET variables are filtered.
}

if ($_POST['doLogin'] == 'Login')
{
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = filter($value); // POST variables are filtered
    }

    $user_email = $data['usr_email'];
    $pass = $data['pwd'];

    if (strpos($user_email,'@') === false) {
        $user_cond = "user_name='$user_email'";
    }
    else {
        $user_cond = "user_email='$user_email'";
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`full_name`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE
               $user_cond
               AND `banned` = '0'
               ") or die (mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated.
    if ($num > 0) {

        list($id, $pwd, $full_name, $approved, $user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        if(!$approved) {
            //$msg = urlencode("Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code");
            $err[] = "Account not activated. Please check your email for activation code";

            //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
            //exit();
        }

        // Check against salt
        if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass, substr($pwd, 0, 9))) {
            // This sets session and logs user in
            session_start();
            session_regenerate_id (true); // Prevent against session fixation attacks.

            // This sets variables in the session
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
            $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

            // Update the timestamp and key for cookie
            $stamp = time();
            $ckey = GenKey();
            mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());

            // Set a cookie

            if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
                setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time() + 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time() + 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
                setcookie("user_name", $_SESSION['user_name'], time() + 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
            }
            if(empty($err)) {
                header("Location: myaccount.php");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
            $err[] = "Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password.";
            //header("Location: login.php?msg=$msg");
        }
    }
    else {
        $err[] = "Error - Invalid login. No such user exists";
    }
}
```

Redirection code:

```
// Connect database
require_once 'dbc.php';

page_protect();

$authorID = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (!empty($_POST["answ_content"]) && $authorID != 0) {
    // Vaqciot html chveulebriv texad
    $content = htmlentities($_POST["answ_content"], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $dro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $qID = $_POST["question_ID"];
    $author = $_SESSION["user_name"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_comments (comment_ID, comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_author_IP, comment_date, comment_content, user_id)
            VALUES
            (NULL, '$qID', '$author', '123.123.123.123', '$dro', '$content', '$authorID')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Pasuxebis raodenobis ertit gazrda
    $increase = "UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_count = comment_count+1 WHERE ID = $qID";
    mysql_query($increase);

    // Gadamisamarteba shekitxvis gverdze
    $url = 'Location:http://example.com/site/answ/question.php?ID=' . $qID;
    header($url);
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and some example addresses that you are redirecting to.

Comment: can you show us some code? are cookies enabled on the users pc? do you use cookies for your sessions or do you always send the session-id as get-parameter and forgot that at your redirect?

Comment: Added all the necessary codes...

Comment: I tested it on several other computers and it works fine... Can't find any explanation...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put `exit();` after your header redirection, otherwise you have just loaded two pages of content into 1 page.

Also make sure you have `session_start();` at the top of all your scripts.

Comment: I added exit(); but it didn't work!

Unfortunately I have to use redirection because of the site structure...

Comment: They key here is session_start(); at the top of all your pages

Answer (score 4):

You aren't starting the session.  In order to use session variables and have them carry across pages, you need to put

```
session_start();
```

at the top of each page before anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to set the session id of my own using:

```
session_id('own_generated_session_id_string');
```

But as [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.session-id.php) says, you have to use this before

```
session_start();
```

Using it after session_start(), clears the session parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Make sure the page you are coming from (for example, *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*) redirects to a (for example, *[www.example.com/redirect.php](http://www.example.com/redirect.php)*) notice *www* at the beginning.

If you change that from page to page, then yes things get wonky.

Comment: Same problem, header redirects were changing from page to page and i switched it to the common scheme used all across the project and voila, it worked.. screwed my ass over this for at least a week... thanks man, you are a saviour...

Answer (score 0):

These sessions does not always work as we expect sometimes. I had a similar problem with my website using sessions that get lost. I basically solved it by injecting the value I want to keep on the session into the hidden text field the first time the page loads. Then the second time I call the page (page submit), I simply read the value from the hidden text field and carry on with rest of my code.

That's easier and cleaner than using sessions in this case!

Comment: It is also very insecure. Some session data is only relevant for the server and should not be exposed to the client.

Comment: Agreed with JoSo, Sessions are cleaner than a viewstate and session data is not considered viewstate data...

Comment: what do you mean by hidden textfield...?textfied that cannot be checked by looking at your html source code?

Answer (score 0):

`exit;` should be placed after header redirection or `session_regenerate_id(true);` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the file permission in the **/var/lib/php** directory.
Give the public permission to the **/var/lib/php/session** directory.

And all is done.

Answer (score 0):

- Include session_start(); in both the files before the session.
- Note don't use session_destroy() in the redirected file.