# Customer redirected from site to PP, session data empties

Tags: php, paypal, session-variables, lamp

I have a cart where the products and shopping cart itself is stored within a session. The session works fine through the entire process, except when the customer goes to PayPal's website. When the customer is redirected to PayPal, then returned to the website, all of the session data is lost.

The session ID remains the same before and after the redirect

I have tried setting the referrer_check variable to no value. Still does not work.

The same code works on my dev server, and I have ensured the settings match up between the dev and live server, for sessions, but I am still not able to save the sessions properly after the return.

I'll provide any settings requested.

I've tried this:
[Session lost after page redirect in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023353/session-lost-after-page-redirect-in-php) (Adding exit() right after redirect)

I'll keep updating things I've tried as I get responses to this.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I ran into this error when I started my session at http://example.com and the return url was http://www.example.com